# Appcode vs Intellij?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, appcode

I cannot seem to find the plugin for appcode in intellij. I've read online that intellij encapsulates all functionality in the other ideas through plugins. However I cannot seem to find the one for appcode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't one. AppCode runs only on a Mac because it depends on a Mac-only toolchain, and uses a different project format (XCode projects instead of IntelliJ's own format). Because of that, it's not possible to release it as a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: What about plugin for swift? Swift open sourced and not tied to macos.